# Multiple ad mob on a single page

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, admob

I am developing an angularjs-cordova app.I am able to load my ad unit on the bottom part of my app.Can I add multiple ad units on a single page ??

And also I am not able to control the postionting of the ad unit.

Is it possible to place the ad unit in the view according to the data loaded dynamicaly

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AdMob help page Tips for [Developers & Publishers](https://support.google.com/admob/#topic=2740022)

The number of ads on a single page should not exceed one if the ad is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, there should be a maximum of one ad on the top and one ad on the bottom, and both ads should not appear on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

More than 1 ad per screen and placing ads replacing app content is against policy. Your app will be rejected (watch the [video here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) or see [documentation here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)).

As Nitin explained, you can place one banner at top and another at bottom if they are not visible at the same time.

Placing ads between the content and the menu is not recommended (and  your app will probably be rejected too as it can be considered to "encourage accidental clicks"). The ad should not be confused with app content (I'm not sure if it is against policy but they clearly mention it in the video as a key point).

If you are using this cordova plugin

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.google
```

you will be able to decide between placing the ads at the bottom or at top (see [cordova admob documentation](http://appfeel.github.io/admob-google-cordova/)):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId: "YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID",
    bannerAtTop: true
  });
  admob.createBannerView();
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```